# How do I open an event viewer file in Excel 2007

Tags: windows-event-log, microsoft-excel

I have an event view that I need to filter and pivot the data from.

I tried exporting the file as a CSV file, but that is missing the description.

I tried exporting the file as XML, but there was no schema, so excel opened it as a table and it was of little to no use.

Is there a way that I can open an event log in excel and be able to pivot / filter on the data, but still retain the description part of the log entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at Microsoft LogParser?

Download [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659)

With LogParser you can do the filtering you want on the Event log files and export to a type that you want. For Example the following command selects everything from the system event log, where type is not information (EventType 4 is "Information Event") and then outputs that data to csv.

```
LogParser "SELECT * INTO c:\report.csv FROM SYSTEM WHERE EventType <> 4" -i:EVT -o:CSV
```

You can filter by what you want by refining the query and the LogParser Helpfile is quite good. Plenty of help is available on the internet too :) You can even generate Charts if you like.

With the query above you can change 'FROM SYSTEM' to 'FROM c:\foldername*.evt' to parse multiple backed-up event log files at once.

Hope this info helps!